# Unable to access global variable through FirefoxDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to retrieve a `JavaScript` global variable's value and I always get `undefined` when I run the test in FireFox.

This test is successful in Chrome.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.seleniumTesting = "Just A Test";
</script>
</head>
<body>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

Test.java

```
WebDriver drive = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost");
// Wait for the page to load. I know there are better ways of doing this.
synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().wait(55000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
String str = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("console.info(window.seleniumTesting); return window.seleniumTesting;");
System.out.println("str: |"+str+"|");
```

When I run this, `str` is `null` and in the browser's JavaScript console `window.seleniumTesting` is logged as `undefined`.

If I use a `ChromeDriver` instead of `FirefoxDriver`. Everything is as expected (`str` is `Just A Test` and the console logs: `Just A Test`).

This seems to be a JavaScript context problem. It seems that in FirefoxDrive the JavaScript context is not the web page's context.

Is this a known issue ? Can I change the driver's JavaScript context to the web page's context ?

[EDIT]
I'm using the `geckodriver` for OSX.

[EDIT] And FireFox version 47.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `null` with `FirefoxDriver` because its working fine on both browser in my case..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes, I'm sure. This is probably cause by the `gecko` driver that I'm using. It may not work with my current FireFox version.

Comment: I'm trying it with current version of firefox with geckodriver and it's working fine in my case. And why are you using `Thread.currentThread().wait(55000);`?? better way to use `executeAsyncScript()` as `(String)((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeAsyncScript("callback = arguments[0]; callback(window.seleniumTesting);");`. may be it helps..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I've just gave it a try with `executeAsyncScript(...)` and I've got the same result. I was using the `wait(...)` call to make sure the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Could you share how are initializing `FireFoxDriver` with `geckodriver` because I'm using `MarionetteDriver` instead to testing it on firefox..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I've downloaded version 0.10.0 from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and added this line in my java program `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers/geckodriver");`

Comment: Oh, but I'm using `0.8.0` of `geckodriver` version, could you try with this downgraded version??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Ok, I will give it a try with 0.8.0. Can you also tell me the selenium version that you're using ?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I'm getting an error `Unknown option --port=16199` with version 0.8.0. I guess this version doesn't work with selenium 3.0.0-beta3

Comment: I'm using last stable version `2.53.1`..:), I would suggest you don't use beta version until stable version of `selenium 3` not getting released, it may have many bugs..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Still the same. I had to use `MarionetteDriver` instead of `FireFoxDriver` to make it work with selenium 2.53.1

Comment: And what about `geckodriver` version??

Comment: I'm using the one that you've mentioned `0.8.0`. I'm doing all this on a OSX system. Also, accessing the DOM seems to work, for example, if I run `var s = document.querySelector('#elm').innerHTML; console.log(s); return s;` the result is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `geckodriver` currently `v0.10.0`, you must use `window.wrappedJSObject` to access a non-standard property of the window object:

```
String str = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.wrappedJSObject.seleniumTesting;");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one and thank you too @SaurabhGaur . How do you know about `window.wrappedJSObject` is it mentioned in some documentation somewhere ?

Comment: @Titus, it is mentioned in the documentation of the marionette driver which is a layer below the gecko driver.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I will look into that, I'm just getting started with all this.